# Mercurial ignoring http_proxy settings

Tags: mercurial

I try to connect to a mercurial alias called 'thuis' throughan http proxy. I tried setting the proxy setting in the .hgrc repo config and in the main config via tortoisehg. With both methods I get an abort error:

```
abort: error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Even using the following construct didn't work:

```
hg --config http_proxy.host=10.192.132.191:5865 --config http_proxy.always=true incoming thuis
```

If I look with MS network monitor I see that hg directly tries to connect to 'thuis' and not to the proxy at 10.192.132.191

Comment: It should work... please come talk to us at http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mercurial or contact the mailinglist: mercurial@selenic.com — that's where the Mercurial developers really are and so you're likely to get much faster response.